# kamailio SIP user Authentication with Xlite and Zoiper

Tags: authentication, kamailio

I am having an issue I have created the user extension (1001) and set password using the below command and I am not able to authenticate user from softphone(xlite and softphone). Kamailio is configured on Redhat-7.2 and I am not able to find any troubleshooting tools or logs that can help me to solve this issue.

```
kamctl add 1001@192.168.254.132 abc@123
```

Service Kamailio is running fine

```
  [root@kamamilio-4-0 ~]# service kamailio status
kamailio.service - SYSV: Kamailio is a fast, reliable and flexible SIP Server.
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/kamailio)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2016-10-08 09:12:07 EDT; 1h 18min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 4014 ExecStop=/etc/rc.d/init.d/kamailio stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 4024 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/kamailio start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

Change the `SIP_Domain /etc/kamailio/kamctlrc` to `IP i.e 192.168.254.132` and also change alias in `/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg`

```
alias=192.168.254.132
```

Running the below command for online user gives the below information.

```
[root@kamamilio-4-0 ~]# kamctl ul show
which: no gdb in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/)
Domain:: location table=1024 records=0 max_slot=0
```

I am not sure what else can be changed to authenticate the user 1001. Can anybody help me regarding this.

Comment: Please check if you have any interesting info in /var/log/messages

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved by disabling the firewalld in redhat 7 use the below two commands to perform this.

```
# systemctl stop firewalld
# systemctl disable firewalld
```

Answer (score 0):

You should follow these step to solve the problem:

1. check whether you are getting register packet on the kamailio server or not.
2. if register packet is not coming then there is problem with firewall. so disable it.
3. if register packet is coming check weather you entered the right password for the extension while registration.
4. if password is right then check then kamailio config.(auth part of that config).